# Where did my file saved into External Storage in Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I can write to Emulator Internal Storage

```
        context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use {
            it.write(outputMode.toByteArray())
        }
```

Or write to Emulator Internal Storage

```
            val file = File(context.filesDir, fileName)
            parseFrom(FileInputStream(file))
```

This works fine.

I can find the file in ./data/data/mypackagename/files/ using Device File Explorer in Android Studio as shown below

[image]

However when I save them in External Storage

using

```
        val path = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
        val letDirectory = File(path, folder)
        letDirectory.mkdirs()
        val file = File(letDirectory, fileName)

        FileOutputStream(file).use {
            it.write(outputMode.toByteArray())
        }
```

I can still read it using

```
            val path = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
            val letDirectory = File(path, folder)
            letDirectory.mkdirs()
            val file = File(letDirectory, fileName)
            parseFrom(FileInputStream(file))
```

But I cannot find it in my Device File Explorer folder. I cannot find it in ./sdcard folder nor ./mnt/sdcard folder.

Where is it stored?

**Note** : This is on Android 11, where I use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: You should look in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.... But file manages have no access to app private directories in Android 11+.

Comment: Is there any way I get the permission or write to a place in sdcard I have permission to see?

Comment: Any public directory on external storage like Download, DCIM, Documents,.. MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE not needed.